# Node classification/regression with Node2Vec

Tags: machine-learning, embeddings

My question is about the correct use of Node2Vec for learning features for node classification/regression.

Suppose we have *n* labeled networks (i.e., networks for which the classes/continuous values of the nodes are known) and *m* unlabeled networks.
Both types of networks are isolated (i.e., the nodes of a given *n* or *m* network do not interact with the nodes of another *n* or *m* network).

The goal is to predict the correct classes/continuous values for the nodes in the unlabeled networks.

The approach I was thinking of using is:

1. Use a single Node2Vec run to learn the embedding vectors for all of the nodes in all networks, both labeled and unlabeled.
2. Train a supervised machine learning algorithm using the output of step 1 and the known classes/continuous values.
3. Use the trained machine learning algorithm from step 2 to predict the classes/continuous values of all of the nodes in the unlabeled networks.

**Is this the correct approach?**

*A similar scenario is described in the documentation of [stellargraph](https://stellargraph.readthedocs.io/en/stable/demos/node-classification/node2vec-node-classification.html), although for a single labeled network.